# how to fix my table width when i don't want it scroll horizontally as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1-my table width goes away of my screen. I want it to be strictly fixed within my screen.
2-how can I show only few lines of table data if its two long. like a td has 1000 character to be shown but I only want the first 100 characters should be shown and the rest should be displayed if I click on that.

your help is much appreciated.

> my html file

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="white-box">
        <h3 class="box-title">Business Opportunities</h3>
        <a href="/update" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right; margin-top: -45px; margin-right: 100px;">Update</a>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-warning" style="float: right; margin-top: -45px" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')">Logout</a>
         
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table   class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Website</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Close Date</th>
                        <th>Weeks Left</th>
                        <th>Downloads</th>
                        <th>Import Date</th>
                        <th>Operation</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for row in output %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.website }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{row.op_link}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></td>
                            <td>{{ row.title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.organization }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.close_date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.weeks_left }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% for link in row.downloads %}
                                    {% if link != '' %}
                                        <a href="{{ link }}">[{{ loop.index }}]</a>
                                    {% else %} 
                                        <p>N/A</p>     
                                    {% endif %}
                                    
                                {% endfor %}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ row.created_at }}</td>
                            <td>
                                # some other codes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your table-responsive class..

```
table-responsive {
  /* your style */
  max-width: 100% !important;   /* set required width */
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

Note: This will set the parent div of the table a *max-width*, and so table content will be displayed within that max-width, by providing a *scrollbar* if the width goes above the max-width.

Answer (score 0):

A `fixed` table layout, combined with the width property, to restrict the table's width. The `text-overflow` property is used to apply an ellipsis to words that are too long to fit.

```
    table {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    td {
      max-width: 50px;
      white-space:nowrap;
      overflow:hidden;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Bootstrap 4.

I have copy pasted your code in the below snippet and everything is working fine.

If you provide me the full code then it will be easy for me to resolve the problem.

Let me know if you need any help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="white-box">
        <h3 class="box-title">Business Opportunities</h3>
        <a href="/update" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right; margin-top: -45px; margin-right: 100px;">Update</a>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-warning" style="float: right; margin-top: -45px" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')">Logout</a>
         
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table   class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Website</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Close Date</th>
                        <th>Weeks Left</th>
                        <th>Downloads</th>
                        <th>Import Date</th>
                        <th>Operation</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for row in output %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
                            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis </td>
                            <td><a href="{{row.op_link}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></td>
                            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
                            <td>{{ row.description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.organization }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.close_date }}</td>
                            <td>Sed ut perspiciatis </td>
                            <td>
                                
                                        <p>Sed ut</p>     
                                    {% endif %}
                                    
                                {% endfor %}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ row.created_at }}</td>
                            <td>
                                # some other codes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you add class container only !?

Comment: Yes I added container class only. So everything should come in center of the screen.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me. anyway I appreciate your consideration.